# Search inside the <li> tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Need help with how to search inside the `li` tag. The `li` list contains the names of employees in the following format [surname,firstname]:

```
Venkata,Anusha  
Raju,Suma
```

HTML CODE:

```
<input type="text"  id="comboBox" placeholder="Search.." />
  <ul id="userList"  class="nobull" style="width: 300px; height: 80px;list-style: none; overflow:auto;padding-left:0;">
```

I used Jquery to search the result

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#comboBox').bind('keydown keypress keyup change', function() {
    var search = this.value;
    var $li = $("#userList li").hide();
    $li.filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    }).show();
});
});
```

It was working fine but only if I search with first Letter as Capital.
Is there any way to make the search case-insensitive and also search based on first name or surname?

Comment: where is the li tag in your code?

Comment: Anyway, $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase())

Comment: Its not working....is there any other way...

Comment: First set text in lowercase for both searched text and li text then alert it or check if both were same text or not. Then try to find index of that text

Answer (score 2):

One possible way could be using regx,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#comboBox').bind('keydown keypress keyup change', function() {
        // this will hide all your li!!!
        $("#userList li").hide();

        // define case-insensitive regx
        var reg = new RegExp(this.value, "i");
        //for each li would you require to match?
        $("#userList li").filter(function() {
           return reg.test($(this).text()); 
        }).show();

     });
});
```

Comment: @AnushaVinod please accept the answer so that it will be useful for others also this question can be closed as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make case-insensitive search, jQuery allows you to add your own selector expressions, and we can use that to build our own contains filter that’s a bit more sensible: Example is like

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
```

This adds a :Contains() (note the uppercase) option to your selectors that does the same as :contains(), but it first converts all text to uppercase, and then compares them. So once we add this to your JavaScript, all we have to do in our listFilter function is replace :contains() with Contains() and we have a fast, simple, progressively-enhanced way to filter down a large list!

You can reffer this link for search feature, 
https://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/
Hope this will help you.